# joomla error arising when transfer site to the other hosting

Tags: joomla

I am trying to transfer Joomla site from one hosting to the other.
The error is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in     /home/.../templates/beez_20/error.php on line 10
```

I have found the folowing lines in error.php:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$params = JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(true)->params;
$logo =  $params->get('logo');
```

Maybe it can't find the parametres, so I should initialize it someway?

Also there are several warnings before fatal error:

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../public_html/libraries/joomla/access/access.php on line 409`

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../public_html/libraries/joomla/plugin/helper.php on line 59`

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../public_html/libraries/joomla/plugin/helper.php on line 59`

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../public_html/libraries/joomla/application/menu.php on line 63`

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../public_html/includes/application.php on line 462`

Comment: I'm sure that you are seeing other notices/warnings before the fatal error. Could you please post them here?

Comment: @itoctopus, yes, here they are:
    `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../public_html/libraries/joomla/access/access.php on line 409`
    `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../public_html/libraries/joomla/plugin/helper.php on line 59`

Comment: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../public_html/libraries/joomla/plugin/helper.php on line 59` 
    `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../public_html/libraries/joomla/application/menu.php on line 63` 
    `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../public_html/includes/application.php on line 462`

Comment: you would probably have more help if you post on the joomla specific stack exchange site here :  http://joomla.stackexchange.com/